# C++ CRTP: how to extend the std::string_view to std::basic_string_view<T> by passing template parameters

Tags: c++, parsing, c++17, crtp, string-view

I'm designing a simple parser, which matches patterns. The code use some CRTP C++ design pattern, I have simplified the code as below.

```
#include <string_view>

template <typename Base>
struct parser_base {
    constexpr auto operator[](std::string_view& output) const noexcept;
};

struct char_ final : public parser_base<char_> {

    constexpr explicit char_(const char ch) noexcept
        : ch(ch)
    {}

    constexpr inline bool visit(std::string_view& sv) const& noexcept {
        if (!sv.empty() && sv.front() == ch) {
            sv.remove_prefix(1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    char ch;
};

template <typename Parser>
constexpr bool parse(std::string_view input, Parser const& parser) noexcept {
    return parser.visit(input);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

You can see that when parsing the `std::string_view`, it builds correctly.

Now, I would like to extent the `std::string_view`, which is actually `std::basic_string_view<char>` to other types, such as I would like to use my own Tokens, so I try to change the code like below:

```
#include <string_view>

template <typename Base, typename T>
struct parser_base {
    constexpr auto operator[](std::basic_string_view<T>& output) const noexcept;
};

template<typename T>
struct char_ final : public parser_base<char_, T> {

    constexpr explicit char_(const T ch) noexcept
        : ch(ch)
    {}

    constexpr inline bool visit(std::basic_string_view<T>& sv) const& noexcept {
        if (!sv.empty() && sv.front() == ch) {
            sv.remove_prefix(1);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

private:
    T ch;
};

template <typename Parser, typename T>
constexpr bool parse(std::basic_string_view<T> input, Parser const& parser) noexcept {
    return parser.visit(input);
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

With the above code, I simply add a second template parameter `T` (which stands for Token) to the `parser_base` class, and the following derived class and functions.

But I got the build error:

```
[ 50.0%] g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -g  -c F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp -o obj\Debug\main.o
F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp:46:49: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<class Base, class T> struct parser_base'
   46 | struct char_ final : public parser_base<char_, T> {
      |                                                 ^
F:\code\test_crtp_twoargs\main.cpp:46:49: note:   expected a type, got 'char_'
```

It looks like the `struct char_` should not be a class template? But how can I pass the `T` type to the `char_` class?

So, any ideas on how to solve my issue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char_` is not a type it's a template, the type is `char_<T>`. So

```
template<typename T>
struct char_ final : public parser_base<char_<T>, T> {
```

Comment: Oh, thanks for the quick answer! It works now. Sorry that I'm not good at C++ template related code. I saw those code just like pure C macros, as they need a lot of replacement. In C macro, it just does text substitute, but in C++'s template, it is more complex, because the deduction is type involved.